# Recursive call of directive crashing the browser tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an observation directive which render observation.html

**observation.js**

```
angular.module('bahmni.clinical')
.directive('observation', function () {

    var controller = function ($scope) {
        console.log($scope.observation);
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: controller,
        scope: {
            observation: "="
        },
        templateUrl: "views/observation.html"
    };
});
```

I call observation directive from the observation.html. This will be done recursively.

**observation.html**

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-field"
         ng-class="{'is-abnormal': observation.abnormal, 'is-text': isText(observation)}">
        <span class="field-attribute"><label>{{observation.concept.shortName || observation.concept.name}}</label></span>
        <span class="value-text-only" ng-if="!observation.groupMembers">{{observation.getDisplayValue()}}</span>
        <span class="label-add-on" ng-hide="!observation.unit"> {{observation.concept.units}}</span>

        <div class="footer-note fr">
            <span class="value-text-only time">{{observation.observationDateTime | date :'hh:mm a'}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div ng-repeat="observationMember in observation.groupMembers">
    <observation observation="observationMember"></observation>
</div>
```

I call this for first time from someother directive.

**someother.js**

```
<observation observation="observation"></observation>
```

If i refresh the browser, The tab will be irresponsive. Don't know what is happening. Not able to debug because of the irresponsive tab.

I would really appretiate your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-include fixed it.

used the following line

**`template: '<ng-include src="\'views/observation.html\'" />'`**

instead of -

*`templateUrl: "views/observation.html"`*

Comment: This was my exact issue. I suppose a bug in Angularjs? I am using version 1.3.0-beta-8. The problem is there are NO errors. Anyone know why this solution mitigates the Chrome browser crash?

Comment: got the same issue...this solution was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an endless loop! I think your problem is how the defined local `scope` variable is defined. `observation`has an two way databinding. So you will overwrite it with every recursive call. Try this to avoid the endless loop

```
 scope: {
        observation: "&"
    },
```

This will create an local directive scope which are not affected from the parent scope.

Keep in mind there will be three ways to define local scope properties you can pass:

- @ Used to pass a string value into the directive
- = Used to create a two-way binding to an object that is passed into the directive
- & Allows an external function to be passed into the directive and
  invoked

**UPDATE 2**

Your main problem seems that your variable `observation` will be overwritten on each recursive call. So you have two options:

- Option 1: You use `@` and serialize your object with `JSON.stringify(observation)`. This string can you provide via string interpolation to your directive. `<observation observation="{{observation}}"></observation>`
- Option 2: You use `&` and pass the object to an helper function, which will be create and return an clone from your object.

Comment: observation is an object, not string. As you say @ is for string values.

Comment: as you said in the answer, & is for external functions. = is for objects.